# Ethernet is not connecting in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ethernet, usb-drive, 22.04

There is no Ethernet Port on my Laptop, so I tried to use an Ethernet to USB-A TP-Link adapter.
It works fine in Windows but does not in Ubuntu.

Please Help

Comment: So what is the Ethernet to USB-A device? And what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Sounds like driver issues. Can you connect over Wifi? If you can, then try going to the drivers tab in software & drivers with the dongle connected and see if a driver is availible there

Comment: @Irsu85 The drivers are not available there. You can find there some drivers, but not this kind of drivers.